# Alternatives to using AWS IoT in US-West-2 connecting to AWS Lambda in US-West-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have hosted IoT in USW2 because USW1 doesnt have IOT support. I created a rule to call with a trigger to call a lambda in USW1.

I followed https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/access-cross-account-resources-using-aws-iot-rules-engine/ but instead of using a cross account ID, i typed in the same account ID so that i just calls the other region. This failed with 404. I dont see a straight forward way of passing my MQTT messages to my computer cluster in USW1. Is there a workaround here.

Answer (score 1):

The cross account lambda execution from IoT rule does work, but the rule and lambda need to be in the same region.

So in your case you'd have

```
USW2 (IoT) -> USW2 (Lambda) -> ... -> USW1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have your account numbers mixed up.

The basic flow is:

- IoT rule from your USW2 account forwards messages to a Lambda function in your USW1 account
- Function in USW2 needs to have permission to be invoked by the USW1 rule